# Typescript | Typing a dynamic class

Tags: typescript, types

I have a class which has multiple child classes, it's pretty much a magic class and does some logic that helps me integrate with a json api.

The class in this case is called `Resource` and the job of this class it to be able to use it pretty much like a Laravel model. So I extend this class and the methods obviously can be used from that class but then I have mutators and other logic on the child class, take this example.

```
class Resource {
    constructor(attributes: Attributes) {
        const keys: string[] = Object.keys(attributes);

        keys.forEach((attributeKey: string) => {
            this.setAttribute(attributeKey, attributes[attributeKey]);

            Object.defineProperty(this, attributeKey, {
                get: () => this.getAttribute(attributeKey),
                set: (value: any) => this.setAttribute(attributeKey, value);
            });
        });
    }

    ...
}
```

```
class User extends Resource {
    setFirstNameAttribute(value: string): void {
        this.attributes.firstName = value.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

This will convert the firstName property on the class to be all uppercase which is done by getters and setters defined in the constructor of the `Resource` class.

It all works perfectly so for example...

```
const user = new User({ firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' });
console.log(user.firstName);
```

Will actually output `JOHN` so all of the logic inside of the parent class is working fine.

The only issue that I find myself with is the types, as the attributes are really set dynamically I can't seem to figure out a way to get this types as I want the methods on the class to be type hinted so `user.find()` will not error but also `user.firstName` will not error but because `firstName` isn't an actual property I cannot figure out a way to hint it.

I've tried to set something like `class Resource<T>` but I'm not sure I fully understand this.

Comment: what about `const user:User = new User(....)`? What does your User class look like? Have you made your members public?

Comment: @Joel I can't believe I never actually thought of this. Are you saying do something like...

`class User extends Resource { firstName!: string; lastName!: string }`

Comment: @tallent123 that solution can work as well. You can then extract the fields from the class to have a properly typed constructor ..

Answer (score 0):

You can add a generic type parameter to represent the type of the attributes. Naively, you would think you could add this generic type parameter to the extends or implement clause of the class (ie `class ResourceBase<T> extends T`) but for a variety of reasons this is not possible.

What you can do is define the base class without the possibility to access the keys dynamically (ie `user.firstName` won't work). You can then cast this base to a generic constructor that returns an intersection of your base class AND the type parameter (`new <T>(attr: T) => ResourceBase<T> & T`). With the condition that you give a concrete type (ie not a type parameter) when you inherit this constructor, everything should work fine.

Note: Also made `getAttribute` and `setAttribute` generic in `K extends keyof T` to fully capture the key and the key type of each attribute.

```
class ResourceBase<T> {
    constructor(protected attributes: T) {
        const keys = Object.keys(attributes) as Array<keyof T>;

        keys.forEach((attributeKey) => {
            this.setAttribute(attributeKey, attributes[attributeKey]);

            Object.defineProperty(this, attributeKey, {
                get: () => this.getAttribute(attributeKey),
                set: (value: any) => this.setAttribute(attributeKey, value);
            });
        });
    }
    getAttribute<K extends keyof T>(key: K) : T[K] {
        return this.attributes[key];
    }
    setAttribute<K extends keyof T>(key: K, value: T[K]) {
        this.attributes[key] = value;
    }
}

const Resource: new <T>(attr: T) => ResourceBase<T> & T = ResourceBase as any


class User extends Resource<{
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string
}> {
    setFirstNameAttribute(value: string): void {
        this.attributes.firstName = value.toUpperCase();
    }
}


const user = new User({ firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' });
console.log(user.firstName);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.8-Beta&ssl=36&ssc=29&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBKCmED2BXATseAhS8A8AKgHzQDeAUNFdMEgHYQAuaKwjSaAFAA5pKPw28ACbQwjZgEsARigEQAXNAIBKMpWqbaDRtADW8AJ4wAvNADy0gFaDGAOgPHO4qbPlrI0AIJo0YQ3iOSABmykQA3OQamlSOEHbBHACiYMAAFpzOEmgycvAA0kZqJiQUMeXQjGmS8RDwjF7ZuQJZrnmFhgA0Yk1uiADaLjl9HQC6KpHRFVSWNmx2wvDBknTwAAp83PBojIacVTXdQ80FRt1l0xUA5vVKnMUkB-E3Db15rcPtRZ1Tl9R1jDuADcwCAUPAlGA6IYHpVqrV6o02i1jiMztAQWD4BNfhUAL446YEyKaPFTF5Iz4CPD5aDwAAeAjowhgQVCxE4jiU+TUSgI-Xyo3U0zQ9XQdDhNTsqLyEH6jlGJOoZM0AMpJxpdMZ8GZrKMITCnKM3O6mPBfIF42FFSe0re8nlRiFZjN8CVVDJZPI2iYcEQqAwEOgqwA7tBCEQPnzYQhkOhMDg6hHoAAyZTQMyxgMJ3BiGBQwxRb3gKDQACqdTQWqZLL9ccDeAuVGWaCYADkwABbINMHJ0K4-TQlxgd7tKXsrK7kPGlKYAgBiklbI678HVfU4rvHUn7KiUQKQklETZitpl8gSS-bq4zGNB4Ls7DL3C2aAAwrh7u7oJ6iz7dCgla3qG5aVpwpDQC215jtAADkABSSBpHQsHdMOo5BrBAAiSDwLBP44j6SAgPAdggEgVycIB2yXsuGETEAA)

Comment: This seems to be what I am looking for and I like the layout of it, I'm just trying to understand it a bit more. The line `keys.forEach((attributeKey) =>` what kind of type would attributeKey be, because originally it was a `string` but now it produces a Typescript error if I leave it as a string, would they all simple become `keyof T`?

Comment: @tallent123 Yes, instead of `string` it should be `keyof T` now. I generally avoi doing a lot of explicit typing in TS. I don't feel it adds any value, on the contrary

Comment: Would this still give me access to methods that are associated to a string? For example `value.match`, would that still be available if I used `keyof T`?

Comment: `keyof T` can actually be a `number` or  a `symbol` as well

Comment: So far so good, but when I do something like `attributeKey.` I only have `.toString()` method available, is there anyway to avoid this and get actual type hints inside of this class?